# Como definir diretório especifico para o Render_template flask?

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask

Estou renderizando um relatório em html utilizando o render_template do Flask. Como padrão o render_template renderiza o que está na pasta template, porém, necessito alterar para que o diretório seja outro. Tentei forçar um diretório padrão mas não obtive sucesso.

```
from flask import Blueprint, request, jsonify, send_from_directory, render_template, Flask

admin = Blueprint('admin', __name__, template_folder='././production/fiscal/relatorios')

return render_template(apuracao.html)
```

Comment: O nome do ficheiro devia estar entre aspas.

Answer (score 0):

app = Flask(**name**,
template_folder="views")

Esse "views", no caso é o nome no qual eu troquei de templates para views. Sendo assim, vc terá que mudar o nome pra views no diretório. (views foi um nome sugestivo. você muda o diretório conforme o nome que vc da no "template_folder="nome que vc deseja mudar")